# AngularJS: ng-switch + ng-repeat with button inside of switch statement

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-switch

I'm pretty new to angular and I'm kind of stuck with an issue. I have an ng-repeat that shows items. In the items I have a "show more info" button, which when you click it should cause the a new view to replace the current one (including the show more info button). The new view would then have a "go back" button which will switch back to the original state.

Unfortunately I can't seem to figure out how to get this to work.

This is as far as I've gotten...

```
<article ng-repeat="item in items" class="items">
  <div ng-switch on="view">
    <div ng-switch-default>
      <p>Default State for {{item}}</p>
      <div class="btn">More Info
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="info">
      <p>Info for {{item}}</p>
      <div class="btn">Go back</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

If someone could help me out here I would appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the value of `view` when button is clicked. I would advise you to use `item.view` instead of `view`, it will prevent view of other elements to be toggled.

```
<article ng-repeat="item in items" class="items">
    <div ng-init="viewDefaultValue = item.view;" ng-switch on="item.view">
        <div ng-switch-default>
            <p>Default State for {{item}}</p>
            <div class="btn" ng-click="item.view = 'info';">More Info</div>
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-when="info">
            <p>Info for {{item}}</p>
            <div class="btn" ng-click="item.view = viewDefaultValue;">Go back</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

Here is an working example.

```js
(function() {
  angular
    .module('myApp', [])
    .controller('myController', function($scope) {
      $scope.items = [{
        view: '',
        text: 'item1'
      }, {
        view: '',
        text: 'item2'

      }]
    });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">

  <div ng-repeat="item in items" class="items">
    <div ng-init="viewDefaultValue = item.view;" ng-switch on="item.view">
      <div ng-switch-default>
        <p>Default State for {{item.text}}</p>
        <div class="btn" ng-click="item.view = 'info';">More Info
        </div>
      </div>
      <div ng-switch-when="info">
        <p>Info for {{item.text}}</p>
        <div class="btn" ng-click="item.view = viewDefaultValue;">Go back</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I see, this seems like the cleanest solution. Thank you very much.

Comment: This actually doesn't seem to be working for me. I tried adding to a "view" to my json object (which is what items contains), but still no luck.

Comment: @IanGray, You have missed a closing `div` after `<div class="btn">More Info` thus it created an HTML issue. I have also added a working example

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you, I was trying to get my code to work but kept getting issues, was about to come back on and ask but your example took care of that.

Answer (score 1):

use `ng-hide` and `ng-show` instead of `ng-switch`

```
<article ng-repeat="item in items" class="items">
  <div ng-show="isviewvisible">
    <div>
      <p>Default State for {{item}}</p>
      <div class="btn" ng-click="more()">More Info
    </div>
    <div ng-hide="isviewvisible">
      <p>Info for {{item}}</p>
      <div class="btn" ng-click="goBack()">Go back</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

now in angularjs

```
$scope.isviewvisible = true;

$scope.more = function(){
  $scope.isviewvisible = false;
}

$scope.goBack = function(){
  $scope.isviewvisible = true;
}
```

when you clicked the `more()` it will hide the view and will show the moreinfo

when you click the `goBack()` it will hide the moreifo and will show the view

Comment: Thanks for the response, that does seem to make more sense. However since this is in an ng-repeat, won't this cause all my items to toggle more info?

Comment: i understand it.can you put what json keys your item object contains.?.we might find something that can replace isviewvisible

Comment: My JSON doesn't current contain a key, but I can add one. So if we had a simple iterated id (1, 2, 3) for each of them. How could I use that to isolate the toggle to the specific item?